# Promise not executing as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

An action should be called after fetchUser action returns a promise. here is the code of fetch user:

```
fetchUser({ commit }, user) {
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (user.uid) { 
          commit("SET_LOGGED_IN", user !== null)
          //  do something ...
          console.log('Resolving promise')
          resolve(user);
          } else {
            commit("SET_USER", null)
            console.log('Rejecting promise')
            reject();
          }

        }
      });
      return promise;
    },
```

and action is

```
someAction: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef, getters }) => {
      let user = getters.user;
      let promise = dispatch('fetchUser', {user});
      console.log(`promise is ${promise}`);

//-----NEVER EXECUTES THIS STEP, SIMPLY GOES BLANK HERE----

      promise.then(function(user) {
      return bindFirestoreRef(
        //dosomething...
      });
      return promise;
    }),
```

Promise not executing as expected. Not sure what I am doing wrong here, the "then" after promise all never executes.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: change let promise=  as return guess it works

Answer (score 0):

In the line where you pass the user you put it in an object under the name `user`.

```
  let promise = dispatch('fetchUser', {user});
```

So you have to access the `user.uid` like `user.user.uid`, just pass the `user` object. Like so:

```
  let promise = dispatch('fetchUser', user);
```

If you add a `catch` to the promise the that one will be fired bec